# Backbone Marionette region close not working

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

How can i close (remove its views) a region in a LayoutView?

I've tried with **LayoutView.[region].close()**, or with **.destroy()** but neither works (undefined functions).

With the eariler version of marionette, the close function worked, but i haven't found this function in the current docs, or in the code.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I found it under region docs. Calling reset() did the job.